# How big of a number will fit in this ASP code?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

```
'   Now get a Location_ID 
'
    Set RS = DB.Execute (AF.SQL("GenerateLocationID"))
    Location_ID = CInt (RS(0).Value)
    RS.Close
```

This is being written to an Oracle database defined with Number(10), but is returning the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0006'
>
> Overflow: 'CInt'

I'm suspicious, because the largest value in the Oracle table now is 32767.  Is it a limit in the code that is creating the ID?

(The AF.SQL("GenerateLocationID") is 'Select Location_ID.NextVal from Dual', so it's just a standard Oracle select statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@thursdaysgeek: Quick fix might be --

```
Location_ID = CLng(RS(0).Value)
```

Or if you want to debug it

```
On Error Resume Next
Location_ID = CInt(RS(0).Value)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Response.Write RS(0).Value
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: With a callout to Ramhound, since he provided the range for CInt.  (Theoretically, he answered the question I asked, but this is the solution I used.)

Comment: @thursdaysgeek: I'll +1 him all the same (despite the "taboo" reference to w3schools) so no worries. ;-)

Comment: It was the first website that came up as a reference.  I noticed the overflow error and realized that he was dealing with a short.  I simply saw the reason he was getting the error.

Answer (score 5):

This should answer your question:

> The CInt function converts an
>   expression to type Integer. Note: The
>   value must be a number between -32768
>   and 32767.

Based on the code it appears that Location_ID would have to be a short.

http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/func_cint.asp